# How asymmetric does a SQUID need to be to characterize the current-phase relationship?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, superconductivity, josephson-junction, mesoscopic-physics

I've been reading the paper Measurement of the Current-Phase Relation of Superconducting Atomic Contacts by Della Rocca et al. from 2007 ([PRL](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.99.127005), [arXiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/0708.0515)).

Here they do measurements on a DC SQUID containing two Josephson junctions
[image]

One of the junctions is an SIS junction with known-current phase relationship $I_0(\phi) = I_0 \sin \gamma$, and their goal is to find the unknown current-phase relationship $I_1(\delta)$ of the second junction.

They do this using an external flux $\phi$, so that the SQUID relations given $\delta - \gamma = \varphi = 2\pi \phi/\phi_0$ and thus $I_{\mathrm{tot}} = I_0 \sin \gamma + I_1(\gamma+\varphi)$. They then go on to assume that $I_0 \gg I_1$, so that the critical current $I_C$ of the SQUID should be reached at $\gamma = \pi/2$, and thus $I_C(\phi) \approx I_0 + I_1(\varphi + \pi/2)$.

They therefore state that by measuring the external flux dependence of the critical current $I_C$ they can reconstruct the current-phase relationship $I_1(\delta)$.

This is all good and well, and I can follow that. But what happens when $I_0 \gg I_1$ does not hold? How much larger does it have to be, and what kind of corrections arise? Can we solve this for a general $I_1(\delta)$, perhaps by expanding it in a Fourier decomposition? Assuming it is an odd function (which it should be for almost any junction), it should be possible to write it as a sum of sines, no matter its exact form.